# What's the canonical way of checking for exhaustive keys union

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to transform and filter certain properties of an instance of a class `Source`. In order to repeat as less code as possible, I decided to start with data available at runtime (my keys name put in an array) and then derive types from there.

I want all that to be type checked so that if there is a new property added to `Source` TS will warn me that I forgot to handle it. This is what I'm doing right now:

```
class Source {
  data = "d";

  meta = "m";

  // if I un-comment this the compilation fails, that is what I want
  // meta2 = "m2";
}

const keysTuple = <T extends Array<keyof Source>>(...args: T) => args;

const dataProps = keysTuple("data");
const metaProps = keysTuple("meta");
```

And that's how I'm checking full "coverage":

```
const _exhaustiveCheck: keyof Source extends
  | typeof dataProps[number]
  | typeof metaProps[number]
  ? boolean
  : never = true;
```

It seems weird having to introduce the `_exhaustiveCheck` variable just for the sake of type checking against `never`, so I was wondering if there is a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to introduce a variable, at least not at runtime.  Purely at the type level you could do something like this:

```
type MutuallyExtends<T extends U, U extends V, V=T> = true;
type ExhaustiveCheck = 
  MutuallyExtends<keyof Source, typeof dataProps[number] | typeof metaProps[number]>;
```

But probably I'd prefer to do something where the compiler error happens right inside the `Source` class where the extra property is added:

```
const keysTuple = <T extends Array<keyof any>>(...args: T) => args;
const dataProps = keysTuple("data");
const metaProps = keysTuple("meta");

type NoExtraKeys<T, K extends keyof T> = Record<Exclude<keyof T, K>, never>;
type DataMetaKeys = typeof dataProps[number] | typeof metaProps[number];
class Source implements NoExtraKeys<Source, DataMetaKeys>
{
  data = "d";

  meta = "m";

  // if you un-comment this the compilation fails right here
  //meta2 = "m2";
}
```

By declaring that `Source` implements `NoExtraKeys<Source, DataMetaKeys>`, any extra keys such as `meta2` will evaluate to something like `Source implements {meta2: never}`, which will fail.

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: In my (real) scenario, the first solution works better since I can't/don't want to modify `Source`. It works perfectly.