# Array of all property names in a type

Tags: typescript

I am using the following code.

```
type PersonRow = {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  phone_number: string;
  age: number;
}

const personColumnNames: (keyof Omit<PersonRow, 'age'>)[] = [
  'name',
  'email',
  'phone_number'
];
```

However I want to get an error when I remove `phone_number` from the personColumnNames (in case a column is ever added to the PersonRow type).

```
type PersonRow = {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  phone_number: string;
  age: number;
}

const personColumnNames: (keyof Omit<PersonRow, 'age'>)[] = [
  'name',
  'email'
];
```

**Edit:**

Here is a hacky way I found but this still seems less than ideal.

```
const personColumnNames = Object.keys(((): { [key in keyof Omit<PersonRow, 'age'>]: null } => ({
  name: null,
  email: null,
  phone_number: null,
}))())
```

Comment: So the only valid value would be an array with three items (`name, email, phone_number`)? Would order matter?

Comment: Yes. Order does not matter.

Comment: Does [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAChBOBnA9gOwErIO5QLxQG8AoKUqVAQwFsIAuKRYeAS1QHMBuEsiKi5gDb1GLdlzJQwACzQQA+qgCuVAEYJhTVp26kKbOuWVr4XAL5EiAYzSNJCFKgDCyActQA5ahER4oAbR0oAHJKGiCAGkCg3n4BCKgAegSoayoaVGAoZEVM4GQGCGgqZkRELSjpWQUjBAjApOCpfiRQAQggxOTU9MzWKDyC6AgADyYKIgBdKAofa1RGLiJQSCgAWRzFCgEBEABRUYhUABNEAB4AFSgR4EOTqABVcIerg+OfADUn999zgD5fABuyGYR0Wy2gcCQaGcrioHi8iAAkogAPIAawoIF862Am22e1eJ1OgTREBAyAAZlAUcVgKdIQ5MFgnkE9O1fk8Ggh4Mh4FApAgIAB+KDFUrlCTgyl2KFOFxuTw0RB+JSqBBTLnwHl8gXwYUvMZEX4cTrkfLc3ki5AYkAAQgsQA) work for you?  If so I'll make an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript - Create an exhaustive Tuple type from another type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58167616/typescript-create-an-exhaustive-tuple-type-from-another-type)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enforce that an array is exhaustive over a union type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55265679/enforce-that-an-array-is-exhaustive-over-a-union-type)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the canonical way of checking for exhaustive keys union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53178218/whats-the-canonical-way-of-checking-for-exhaustive-keys-union)

Answer (score 1):

For typing an array with Typescript, you have two options.

1. The common `SomeType[]` which says "I have an array, and each item in that array is `SomeType`. This won't work for you because there is no way to type the length, and each item cannot be dependent on any other item.
2. A tuple: `[TypeA, TypeB, TypeC]`. This represent an array of fixed length, where the item type at each index is known. This won't work for you because the order matters. I also do not believe you can create this type with a dynamic length.

So do I not believe there is a way to do what you want. And without knowing how you are planning to use this array, it's hard to suggest an alternative.